# Not getting updated related records after receiving event sent over Push Topic

Tags: lightning-web-components, batch, pushtopic

I have created one `Push Topic` for one of my custom objects i.e. `LogInfo`. This custom object is responsible for storing the status of Apex Batch job. So the object stores the Job status from `AsyncApexJob` object.

the **query** to which I have subscribed is as follows and `NotifyForFieldValue` is `Referenced`

> SELECT Id, JobId__c,JobStatus__c,JobType__c,ExtendedStatus__c FROM
>   LogInfo__c

the **payload**  that I received is

```
{
  "data": {
    "event": {
      "createdDate": "2020-04-28T07:10:24.701Z",
      "replayId": 16,
      "type": "updated"
    },
    "sobject": {
      "JobId__c": "707J000001Iz5xOIAR",
      "JobType__c": "SYNC",
      "ExtendedStatus__c": null,
      "JobStatus__c": "Completed",
      "Id": "a03J000001JiuBFIAZ"
    }
  },
  "channel": "/topic/JOBSTATS"
}
```

In my `lwc` component  I am subscribing to the event for the event.

```
handleSubscribe() {
        let self = this;
        const messageCallback = function(response) {
            if(typeof response != 'undefined'){

                let obj = response.data.sobject;
                  if(obj.JobStatus__c=='Completed'){

                     // get the obj.Id and fetch the related record 
                     // for example SELECT count() FROM SyncObj WHERE LogInfo__c =:obj.Id
                     // But no updated results I get

                  }
            }
        };

        subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then(response => {
            this.subscription = response;
        });
    }
```

Now, when the `obj.JobStatus__c` is `Completed` I am trying to use the value `Id` field and accessing the related records from another object. In which `LogInfo` object is set as `lookup  relation`.

But the problem is whenever I fire a query to access related data, it shows the old data, not the updated one. Even after the job is completed and all changes have been made to `SyncInfo` object in execute method of Apex Job , When I query the related `SyncInfo` object after receiving the event I get old data.

Comment: Are you querying/calling an Apex method? If yes then is that marked as `cacheable`?

Comment: Ahh thts corrent !! thanks

Comment: Great! added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling an Apex method for querying data and it is marked as `cacheable` then you may get stale data.

You can remove the `cacheable` but it may have performance degradation based on frequency of apex.